# Google App Engine Custom Domain in Namecheap

Tags: google-app-engine, dns

I was following [this tutorial](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/domain) to set up a custom domain for my google app engine app. I have done everything outlined here I believe, I've proved to Google that the domain is mine, chosen the first option (the example.com, not the something.example.com) and clicked add, and updated the "All Host Records" thing in Namecheap (my domain name provider). I put all the 8 urls (4 A records [3digits.3digits.2digits.2digits] and 4 AAA records [4digits: 4digits:4digits:2digits::2digits] with subdomain "www").

It's been two days, does it really take this long or have I done something wrong?

Oh and when I visit the domain name, it sends me to a Google 404 page. The one with the robot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe the A records are only for the root domain(no www). If you are using www or any subdomain you need to cname it to ghs.googlehosted.com

Comment: Hi! How about the AAAA records? Do I put them in the root domain "@" too?

Comment: If you want to serve it on root domain too. I usually just use namecheap to redirect to www.